# Is there an 11.04 package for gtk+-3.2.0?

Tags: 11.04, package-management, gtk3

gtk+-3.2.0 has been out since 26-Sep-2011. When will there be a package available for Ubuntu natty? I've tried building it myself but it's very difficult, all I get are errors. The references pages aren't very much help there too advanced.

---

I installed the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev zlib1g-dev fam libdbus-1-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev gobject-introspection libxext-dev libxrender1-dbg colordiff libcairo2-dev libtiff4-dev libpng12-dev libxft-dev libxi-devel
```

I have the dir /home/me/gtk there I have the folders:

```
atk-2.1.5
gdk-pixbuf-2.24.1
glib-2.30.1
gtk+-3.2.3
pango-1.29.1
```

Then:

```
cd /home/me/gtk/glib-2.30.1
./configure && make
rm -rf /home/me/gtk/include/glib.h  /home/me/gtk/include/gmodule.h  (glib INSTALL instructions)
make install
```

repeat for the other folders except without the rm, in the following order:

1. atk-2.1.5
2. gdk-pixbuf-2.24.1
3. pango-1.29.1
4. gtk+-3.2.3

Before running ./configure for gtk+-3.2.3 I do:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/home/me/gtk/include"
LDFLAGS="-L/home/me/gtk/lib"
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/home/me/gtk/lib/pkgconfig"
export CPPFLAGS LDFLAGS PKG_CONFIG_PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/me/gtk/lib"
PATH="/home/me/gtk/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH PATH
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/home/me/gtk/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
```

I get the these errors when I run make on gtk+-3.2.3:

```
gdkwindow-x11.c: In function '_gdk_x11_moveresize_handle_event':
gdkwindow-x11.c:4301:9: error: 'XIEvent' undeclared (first use in this function)
gdkwindow-x11.c:4301:9: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
gdkwindow-x11.c:4301:18: error: 'ev' undeclared (first use in this function)
gdkwindow-x11.c:4301:33: error: expected expression before ')' token
gdkwindow-x11.c:4302:9: error: 'XIDeviceEvent' undeclared (first use in this function)
gdkwindow-x11.c:4302:24: error: 'xev' undeclared (first use in this function)
gdkwindow-x11.c:4302:46: error: expected expression before ')' token
gdkwindow-x11.c:4306:16: error: 'XI_Motion' undeclared (first use in this function)
gdkwindow-x11.c:4308:13: warning: implicit declaration of function '_gdk_x11_device_xi2_translate_state'
gdkwindow-x11.c:4313:16: error: 'XI_ButtonRelease' undeclared (first use in this function)
make[4]: *** [gdkwindow-x11.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/me/gtk/gtk+-3.2.3/gdk/x11'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/me/gtk/gtk+-3.2.3/gdk'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/me/gtk/gtk+-3.2.3/gdk'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/me/gtk/gtk+-3.2.3'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you provide additional details on what error messages you are encountering while trying to build gtk+? We might be able to help you work around them.

Comment: First of all, I have to ask why do you want to do this? Why not just upgrade to 11.10?

Answer (score 2):

There won't be.  11.04 is a stable release, so it doesn't get new upstream releases, except for a few special cases like firefox.  Unless someone adds it to the natty-backports repository, but backports doesn't see much activity, especially on non LTS releases.